# Firefox won't display full sized images (javascript app)

Tags: javascript, css, image, reactjs, firefox

I'm building a javascript (MERN stack) app that involves displaying images. On click, users can "zoom in" on an image (e.g., view full sized image). This works in all major browsers except for Firefox. I tried playing with the image styling settings, but no progress.

After googling around, it seems that this is a known issue with Firefox--it automatically makes images fit to screen size. I've yet to come across a fix.

Are there any known fixes for this?

Thanks!

Comment: There's the browser setting, and it used to allow full size viewing with a click. Those may be the only solutions still, don't know what recent versions have changed though.

Comment: Yes, I read about the browser setting, but that is dependent on the user knowing about the browser setting. Is there really nothing that can be done code-wise to solve this?